# THREE.js sparse planeBufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, gis, arcgis-js-api

I have a file with sparse elevations.  It is based off of gps data.  I have been using this data to populate an PlaneBuffer array with elevations.

```
var vertices = new Float32Array( (grid.NCOL*grid.NROW) * 4 );
for (var i = 0, q = vertices.length; i < q; i++){
        vertices[ i*3 + 0 ] = parseInt(i % (grid.NCOL+1)*4);
        vertices[ i*3 + 1 ] = parseInt(i / (grid.NCOL+1)*4);
    //  vertices[ i*3 + 2 ] = null; // makes no difference

    }
for (var i = 0, l = grid.NODES.length; i < l; i++) {
        var nodeNumber = grid.NODES[i][0];
        var elevation= grid.NODES[i][1];
        vertices[ nodeNumber*3 + 2 ] = elevation;
    }
```

My problem is that there are nodes that the elevation values are unknown(Vertex array is sparse with elevations) and should be represented by holes/cutouts in the plane.  What I end up with is the null elevations being interpreted as 0 not as holes.  I have started down the path of using a [rawshader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.html), but still not sure that making null values transparent is the correct method.

The below picture shows my issues.  The circled area is a high wall that should not be there, because it triangulating to the "null/0" floor.  The red-lines area is where we should have a hole.
[image]

EDIT:
Maybe this picture will help to.  It is from the bottom.  The null elevations being set to zero block the view of the plane and cause the edge of the plane to be triangulated to 0 elevation:[image]

Here is what our desktop application displays.  Notice the edges of the plane are not triangulated down to zero but instead left sharp?
[image]

Comment: Looks like a hole to me. What exactly are you trying to do? How should your code treat null elevations?

Comment: It's not a hole because the surface is being triangulated down to 0, instead of cutting it off.  I want it to be transparent, null elevations should be treated as unknown and transparent instead of as 0.  It looks like a hole because it is black.

Comment: If you want to cull those vertices you'll have to do it manually. THREE.js doesn't have any built in CSG operations to subtract geometry. If you want it to be a continuous surface with transparent bits, a shader is probably the way to go.

Comment: @user2061883 Your use case seems more appropriate for a point cloud with `THREE.Points`. http://potree.org/demo/potree_1.3/showcase/ca13.html

Comment: Found this http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/ Would it be worth a look to try and subtract all null nodes?

Comment: @WestLangley  The point cloud solution work okay but i no longer am able to us the triangulation that was available from altering a pre existing surface.  I'm still thinking that planeBufferGeometry should handle NULL values in elevation more gracefully?

Comment: @user2061883 Try adding a per-vertex attribute to your buffer geometry that is 1 for valid data and 0 otherwise, and pass it as a varying to the fragment shader. In the fragment shader, the attribute will be averaged. If the attribute value in the fragment shader is less than 1, then at least one vertex is invalid. Use the `discard` statement in the fragment shader to discard the fragment. You will have to use `ShaderMaterial` to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plane buffer Geometries take a Float32Array.  This array is default set to 0.  Using `undefined` setter allowed me to set the sparse array out of the float32 type.  Attempts to set any value to `null` and `NanN` did not work.

RTFM:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array

final result as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems more appropriate for a point cloud with THREE.Points. potree.org/demo/potree_1.3/showcase/ca13.html – WestLangley 14 mins ago

This example helped:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_points